# Paypal IPN return datetime formatting

Tags: php, datetime, paypal, paypal-ipn

Palpal sandbox IPN returning datetime as `Mon Jun 15 2015 12:04:00 GMT+0600 (Azores Standard Time)`. How to format this in PHP? Please look at my date format. This is not duplicate.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Convert one date format into another in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2167916/convert-one-date-format-into-another-in-php)

Comment: @Uchiha This is not duplicate. Please see first my returning format

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you remove `(Azores Standard Time)` your date will become valid, and then you can use `strtotime()` or `DateTime`:

```php
$string = 'Mon Jun 15 2015 12:04:00 GMT+0600 (Azores Standard Time)';
$string = substr($string, 0, strrpos($string, '(') - 1);
$dt = new DateTime($string);
echo $dt->format('c \o\r U');
```

<kbd>**[demo](https://eval.in/381490)**</kbd>

Comment: awesome... Thanks :)