# How to convert date format using php

Tags: php, date

I have a date in php in the format as `Tue Jun 16 2015 05:30:00 GMT 0530 (India Standard Time)`

I want to convert it in format `mm-DD-YYYY`

How can I do it ?

I have tried to use

```
$old_date_timestamp = strtotime($curddat);
echo $new_date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $old_date_timestamp);
```

but it is giving result

`1970-01-01 00:00:00`

While the value of `$curddat` is `Tue Jun 16 2015 05:30:00 GMT 0530 (India Standard Time)`

Comment: Get rid of `0530 (India Standard Time)`, and use `'m-d-Y'`. [Like this](https://eval.in/private/2af8c229a8fd73)

Comment: Same question: http://stackoverflow.com/a/30839577/67332

Answer (score 1):

```
echo $old_date_timestamp = strtotime('Tue Jun 16 2015 05:30:00'); //GMT 0530 (India Standard Time) not needed
echo $new_date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $old_date_timestamp);

//output 2015-06-16 05:30:00
```

Answer (score 0):

`strtotime` can't convert your string to data when you have extra `India Standard Time` and so on. 
Just remove that:

```
$curddat = 'Tue Jun 16 2015 05:30:00 GMT 0530 (India Standard Time)';
$curddat = str_replace(' GMT 0530 (India Standard Time)','',$curddat);

$old_date_timestamp = strtotime($curddat);
echo $new_date = date('m-d-Y', $old_date_timestamp);
```